# New React module inside another react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component, react-slick

So if it's silly question, please excuse me.

I'm using React Carousel Component (react-slick) for my project. What i want to achieve, inside this block i want to use my module "**CarouselSlide**".

```
<Slider {...settings}> //--> react-slick component tag
  <CarouselSlide/>     //--> my module
</Slider>
```

CarouselSlide is my react module shows single carousel slide.

Is it possible to use this way or do i have to edit "**react-slick**" component own source code ?

Comment: have you tried it? seems like you should be able to get a pretty definitive answer

Comment: Sorry, i forget to point out that i have tried but it doesn't render all sliders, according to json data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how you want to display the slides, the base `react-slick` my prove difficult since that component seems to display each sibling element in its own slide. The problem with using your own React component as a child for `react-slick` is that your component must return a single parent and there currently is no way of sending multiple sibling elements in your `render` function's return statement.

`react-slick` seems to want a setup like the following:

```
<Slider {...settings}>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
</Slider>
```

Yet creating a component in React and returning

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
```

Would return an error since you need a single parent encapsulating the return statement.

Now instead if you had a more complicated component to define EACH slide you can then do something like:

```
<Slider {...settings}>
    <MyComponent />
    <MyComponent />
</Slider>
```

So it really boils down to how you use it. If you want to return the ENTIRE set of slides in a single component, you'll need to edit the base `react-slick` component to allow that.

Take a look at this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d2smrfhp/) and you can see the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, for your answer. I am a react newby so i wanted to learn if possible or it's nonsense. I think there will be a lot of coding.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it possible .You can components inside components.This is how react works

Comment: i forget to point out but i have tried but it doesn't render all sliders, according to json data. Like Fizz said.